# How to update multiple records of Rails forms at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very simple table on an index page displaying values within my "order_packages" table. I would like to have each table row allow the user to update the value for the "price" field of each individual order. After the user is done inputing as many price as they want, I would like there to be 1 submit button that updates all the orders at once. Here is my existing code:

```
<tbody>
    <% @order_packages.each do |order| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= order.id %></td>
        <td><%= order.created_at.try(:strftime, '%b %e %y') %></td>
        <td><%= order.package.name %></td>
        <td><%= order.student.school.name %></td>

        <%= simple_form_for(order) do |f| %>
          <%= f.error_notification %>

            <td><%= f.input :price, :label => false, :id => "price" %></td>
            <td><%= f.button :submit, "Update Order" %></td>

        <% end %>

        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_package_path(order) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Currently, each individual order has its own submit button that only updates that order exclusively. How can I update all of the orders with a single button? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can have the same field multiple times in the form, this should enable it to be sent as an array of fields.

```
 <tbody>
    <%= simple_form_for(order) do |f| %>
      <% @order_packages.each do |order| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= order.id %></td>
          <td><%= order.created_at.try(:strftime, '%b %e %y') %></td>
          <td><%= order.package.name %></td>
          <td><%= order.student.school.name %></td>


          <td><%= f.input :price, :label => false, :id => "price", multiple: true %></td>

          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_package_path(order) %></td>
  </tr>
    <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Update Order" %> 
 <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Notice the **multiple: true** param on price field, that's simple_form's way of rendering the input as an html array input. Also, to render the activemodel validation errors you will need to do some more work depending on how you want it to look.